# Is it possible to create a Rest API using Jupyter notebook?,if yes How to create Rest API for the following code interms of json format

Tags: python, mysql, time-series, jupyter-notebook

I have built a model for the time series analysis which is going to predict the sail for the next days,the model is working fine,but i want to convert that into Rest API in JSON format using the Anaconda jupyter notebook,Please let me know the way for that .Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
from pandas import Series
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import numpy

# create a differenced series
def difference(dataset, interval=1):
     diff = list()
for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
    value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - interval]
    diff.append(value)
return numpy.array(diff)

# invert differenced value
def inverse_difference(history, yhat, interval=1):
   return yhat + history[-interval]

# load dataset
  series = Series.from_csv('mkr.csv', header=None)
# seasonal difference
X = series.values
X = X.astype('float32')
days_in_year = 365
differenced = difference(X, days_in_year)


 # fit model
 model = ARIMA(differenced, order=(0,0,1))
 model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)

# multi-step out-of-sample forecast
 forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=7)[0]

# invert the differenced forecast to something usable
history = [x for x in X]
day = 1
 for yhat in forecast:
    inverted = inverse_difference(history, yhat,days_in_year)
    print('Day %d sail:= %.3f' % (month, inverted))
    history.append(inverted)
    day += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

There are hopeful google search results for this problem found by 'jupyter notebook rest api', e.g. https://blog.ouseful.info/2017/09/06/building-a-json-api-using-jupyer-notebooks-in-under-5-minutes/

Have you tried using kernelgateway?

Comment: No i have not tried with that, will you share me the links if you know any tutorial of building rest api using kernelgateway?

Comment: I guess a link above a  bit overloaded. Here, this guy made a super easy first steps description https://ndres.me/post/jupyter-notebook-rest-api/ with downloading jupyter_kernel_gateway and designating a function to the GET method. Basically, all you have to do is designate a function to a REST verb and print a result.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install jupyter server proxy, this project allows to implement a REST API in the notebook

https://github.com/gbrault/jpjwidgets

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @Pangur answer, for a complete documentation from jupyter:
https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http-mode.html

You can generate even swagger as in below:
**Once cell**

```
# POST /person
req = json.loads(REQUEST)
row_id = person_table.insert(req['body'])
res = {'id' : row_id}
print(json.dumps(res))
```

**Next cell (companion cell):**

```
# ResponseInfo POST /person
print(json.dumps({
    "headers" : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    },
    "status" : 201
}))
```

**Swagger:**
https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http-mode.html#swagger-spec

**Full demo:**
https://github.com/jupyter/kernel_gateway_demos/tree/master/scotch_demo